# How to approach saving an instance of an object for later re-use in a vanilla js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, javascript-objects

I'm running into an issue converting some old jQuery plugins into Vanilla JS. Take owlCarousel plugin for example -> https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/develop/src/js/owl.carousel.js

```
$.fn.owlCarousel = function(option) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data('owl.carousel');

        if (!data) {
            //WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS!
            data = new Owl(this, typeof option == 'object' && option);
            $this.data('owl.carousel', data);

            $.each([
                'next', 'prev', 'to', 'destroy', 'refresh', 'replace', 'add', 'remove'
            ], function(i, event) {
                data.register({ type: Owl.Type.Event, name: event });
                data.$element.on(event + '.owl.carousel.core', $.proxy(function(e) {
                    if (e.namespace && e.relatedTarget !== this) {
                        this.suppress([ event ]);
                        data[event].apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
                        this.release([ event ]);
                    }
                }, data));
            });
        }

        if (typeof option == 'string' && option.charAt(0) !== '_') {
            data[option].apply(data, args);
        }
    });
};
```

In the plugin definition I store the `new Owl('stuff');` in `$el.data` and retrieve the instantiated object at a later point to call methods on it etc.

`const owlObj = $owl.data('owl.carousel');`

This also allows me to have multiple instances of the plugin accessible through DOM elements.

Is this paradigm thrown out the window in Vanilla JS? What's the best way to store the instantiated objects and retrieve them at a later date?

Cheers!

Comment: is your solution not working?  that is what I would do; instantiate the object, assign it to a variable and call it at will.  If there are many of them, I would put them into an object so I could iterate through them etc...

Comment: When it comes to changing this plugin to Vanilla JS I cannot use jQuery.data() and therefore cannot store the instantiated object on the element to retrieve it later. Am I just thinking about it it the wrong way? Could putting them into an object cause a memory leak?